# PatIndex() match Select Substring

Tags: sql-server, substring

I am trying to form the correct `If` or `Case statement` to select a `Substring` only when there is a match from the `PatIndex()` function.

The below query works partially. The problem is where there is not a match in `PatIndex()` it returns 0 then the `substring` function returns the 4 characters starting at the column 3 from every other URL returned. I wan to skip these URL that don't match the pattern.
I have tried

`Case PatIndex('%ID=%',URL) > 1`

But I get a syntax error near '>' not sure why.

```
select distinct Url, Username, substring(Url, (PatIndex('%ID=%', Url)+3), 4) as RID 
from tblWebSiteUsage
where dateandtime > '2-16-2018 12:00:00 am'
```

Comment: Can't tell you why you get a syntax error unless you post the full query that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can only filter `URL`s which have `ID=` by using WHERE clause :

```
WHERE Url LIKE '%ID=%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Updated query to get URL's which contains only string 'ID='.

```
select distinct Url, Username, substring(Url, (PatIndex('%ID=%', Url)+3), 4) as RID 
from tblWebSiteUsage
where dateandtime > '2-16-2018 12:00:00 am' and Url like '%ID=%'
```

Comment: One feature of a good answer is some accompanying text to provide an explanation, in addition to the solution, to ensure the solution is useful for years to come. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

This case statement should check if there's a pattern match before pulling the ID from your url and returns null if there is no ID= in the url

```
select 
    distinct Url, 
    Username,
    case when PatIndex('%ID=%', Url) > 0 
         then substring(Url, (PatIndex('%ID=%', Url)+3), 4) 
         else null
    end as RID 
from tblWebSiteUsage
where dateandtime > '2-16-2018 12:00:00 am'`
```